# Scale and Translate animation for a Dialog given X and Y

Tags: android, dialog, scale, translate-animation

I'm trying to animate a Dialog enter and exit animation over a MapView in the following way: After the user executes a longPress on an OverlayItem of the MapView, the Dialog should scale and translate from the longPress' X and Y coordinates to the center of the screen. Similarly, when the user dismisses the Dialog it should scale and translate to the X and Y coordinates it originally came from.

My biggest problem is that I can't find a way to start the animation for a given X and Y (and I'm not sure if it can be done either).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: don't do it, there are enough animations and sometimes it can be overkill, I wouldn't want to see that kind of animation every single time you opened an item, unless it was less than 500ms, or something really short. With that said, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518995/positioning-a-dialog-on-screen duplicate?