# Is there a way to show up dialog from BEHIND a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I made a nice dialog with appearing animation in my app. But there is a little problem:
I need to slide it to screen behind from a simple header bar. The header bar contains a simple graphic and a textView with my app's name so this dialog must be slide in UNDER or BEHIND from it if you know what i mean..

Question:

Is there a masking option to not show the dialog in that part of the layout or something else to achieve such an effect?

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.  Dialogs are modal so they are always on top and block focus.

You may be able to reposition the window itself, see [Positioning a dialog on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4518995/808940)
but you won't be able to mask it as such.

As for animating dialogs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591827/808940