# How to set the custom dialog on exact location when i click on view in android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, customdialog

When I click on image then custom dialog is show on Top of the screen so Please can any one suggest me that how to set custom dialog at the exact location that was clicked

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]  when i am click on ![enter image description here][2] this image then i want that on this image ![enter image description here][3] this dialog is show please check these links and suggest me


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5rrgU.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fhvu5.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uSnZx.png

Comment: Please edit your question and include the above comment in the body of your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518995/positioning-a-dialog-on-screen

Comment: actually i want to send the screenshot of my question in the body but there is not possible for set the image url so.Here is one comment and in this comment edited my question please read it

Comment: @NeelamGoyal u can use twitter or dropbox/drive to share link and can post in comments

Comment: you can set gravity TOP for your custom dialog.

Comment: No when i scroll the view then dialog is show at top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can check-out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469005/show-alertdialog-in-any-position-of-the-screen) if you want to stick to custom dialog, but if you are interested then you can use pop up window instead of custom dialog, its very easy to use popup window and you can position it nice and easy.

Comment: same at the same time..:)

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose u can use PopupWindow to fit the view at location u want. u can setcontentview here as well similar to custom dialog.